# my Pi-Top 3 wont power down on shutdown

Tags: noobs, shutdown, pi-top

I am running Noobs, it boots fine and runs fine but when I shut down the screen stays powered on, etc. What shout I tweak? I've already tried shutting down from the console, checked Hardware/software configurations, all seems fine but still wont completely power down.

Comment: how is the screen powered?

Comment: Is it even supposed to be powered down?

Comment: Firstly I would avoid Noobs, try a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS. Maybe ask on the PiTop3 forum https://forum.pi-top.com/c/pi-top-3

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, Yes, I also have a Pi 400 and it powers down after shutdown.

Comment: @CoderMike I intalled Raspberry Pi and it still wont Turn off. ? hardware issue? I've gone through raspi-config but nothing to tweak there, etc. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Noobs isn't really an operating system and isn't meant to be shut down. You are supposed to use it only on the first boot to choose a real OS.

Comment: I just installed Raspberry Pi but it still happens.